# Error when trying to implement FB authentication into iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

I'm having issues when trying to run my first social network program. I've been following Mark Prices iOS programming guide for Swift 3 and my issue comes about when I try to login to FB. When I login the screen turns white and then in my error dialog it shows:

**2016-10-17 13:35:16.744 sinogrecosocialnetwork[31605:]  Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not found. Please add the handler into your App Delegate. Class: sinogrecosocialnetwork.AppDelegate**

And I'm not entirely sure what it means. I've tried rewriting everything that the tutorial shows me, but I'm lost. What can I do to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you implemented func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool in app delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is clearly saying you have not implemented application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: ,Implement the following method in app delegate (make sure you have also added the required keys in info.plist refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 ):

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, 
     openURL: url, 
     sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String,
     annotation: options [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

and for lower version support

```
@available(iOS, introduced=8.0, deprecated=9.0)
func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {  
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
     openURL: url,
     sourceApplication: sourceApplication!,
     annotation: annotation)
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add the: " @available(iOS 9.0, *) " at the top, thank you!

Comment: @idionysis - then you can mark my answer as right so that others can get helped from this answe,r if they face the same problem.